# Why am I getting some white, bleached leaves on my miltoniopsis?

Tags: diagnosis, orchids

I have two miltoniopsis divisions that have leaves that are turning white.  Any ideas on what the problem might be?  They were divided from a larger plant about 4 months ago and are growing in cocnout bark in clear plastic pots that have aeration slots in them.  They've been watered every 3-4 under the tap and allowed to drain on the drainboard before placing them back in a southern exposure.

I've tried to upload an image - the jpeg taken with my samsung galaxy is too large?  Hard to believe.  I also tried to input a link to the verizon cloud copy of the image, but it tells me the format isn't correct - it's just a web address.

Comment: Please add an image

Comment: Hi LarryH. This question is not [specific enough](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). More than anything we need pictures. We always do, but they're essential with [diagnosis](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/diagnosis/info) questions. We'd also like the age of the plants, growing conditions, and other factors.  [It may end up [on-hold or closed](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). If that happens, you can always edit and reopen it!

Comment: @Sue questions rarely get re-opened.  Either he puts up a picture or it gets closed.

Comment: @GrahamChiu That's frequently true, but more often with brand new users. I'm hoping this case may be different because OP is already active on the site, and has been seen here recently. Even if it gets closed, it's still visible and I hope my instructions will help someone else!

Comment: Can you do a google image search of 'orchid leaf issues' and find a picture that looks similar to your issue?